# Client XAML Customization in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I am working in Silverlight 4.0 and have created a web application which is intended to be used as a utility for others.  I have set up several screens using XAML in particular configurations as the UI, however I imagine that some people would like the option to customize the pages of the application.  Is there a way they can do this?  The XAML is not in the XAP file, it is compiled into a DLL, so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on what kind of customization you want to offer your users.  If you want users to be able to rearrange elements of the UI, you would not have them modify XAML.  You would want to implement a "web part" interface in which users can move elements of the screen around, similar to Visual Studio.  The major control vendors (e.g. Telerik, Intersoft, etc) include a Docking-style control.

Comment: Thank you, I will research this.

Comment: The customization would be a one-time deal for each system the UI was installed upon.  Basically, we would like to avoid distributing new DLLs just to make minor adjustments to the screen.